# What does it mean for a function to be “uniformly approximated by” some sequence of functions?

Tags: definition, uniform-convergence

I just want to double check some terminology, as it’s not formally been defined, but I’m pretty sure this is what this means. I’ve been given the statement of a theorem:

> **Weierstrass Approximation Theorem:** For $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous, $f$ can be *uniformly approximated by* polynomials.

Presumably by “uniformly approximated by” we mean there exists a sequence $f_1, f_2, \dots$ of (in this case, polynomial) functions such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly? That is,

$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \forall x \in [a,b], \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall n \geq N, |f_n-f| < \epsilon.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. The norm $\|f\|=\max_{x\in [a,b]} |f(x)|$ is sometimes called the *uniform norm*. Uniform approximation of $f$ by members of a set $\mathcal{P}$ means approximation in the uniform norm (that is, $\inf_{p\in \mathcal{P}}\|f-p\|=0$). Which is the same as what your sequential characterization.

Comment: That's right if $|\cdot|$ is your notation for the sup norm. Otherwise you should say $\cdots \forall n \ge N \forall x \in [a, b]. |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: You've quantified over $x$, but $x$ is not used anywhere in your expression.  If $|f_n - f| < \epsilon$ means $\sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f_n(x) - f|$ (aka uniform norm) then you don't need to quantify over $x$.